# Under what conditions does Latinate -ia correspond to -ei vs. -ien in place names?

Tags: etymology, suffix, latin

Many toponyms (place names) that in English or Latin end in *-ia* end in *-ien* in German.  For example:

Croatia → Kroatien
Czechia → Tschechien
Romania → Rumänien
Serbia → Serbien
Macedonia → Mazedonien
Albania → Albanien
Bulgaria → Bulgarien
Abkhazia → Abchasien
Gagauzia → Gagausien
Transnistria → Transnistrien

However, many other toponyms that end in *-ia* in English or Latin end in *-ei* in German:

Slovakia → Slowakei
Manchuria → Mandschurei
Wallachia → Walachei
Mongolia → Mongolei
Cassubia → Kaschubei
Hanakia → Hanakei
Tartaria → Tartarei

Is there any basis for this distinction (be it historical, etymological, orthographical, morphological, or phonological), or is it completely arbitrary?

Comment: Concerning "ei" read https://taz.de/Verachtung-im-Suffix/!1231813/

Comment: Note your example toponyms are all country names - Cities and other place names are entirely different. (*Colonia* - Köln, '*Roma* - Rom,....)

Comment: Nur eine kleine weitere Fallgruppe: Hungaria -> Ungarn. Gibt es noch mehr Fälle in dieser Gruppe?

Answer (score 4):

##### The most probable factor is the time the name is coined.

There are basically three ways to make a country name out the name of the people:

1. The probably oldest is just "-en", like in "Sachsen", "Hessen"
   (German tribes), but also "Schweden", "Polen", "Böhmen", which are
   all (relatively) close to Germany. A comment in [Wiktionary on
   -ien](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-en#German) suggests it is a dative plural, that would make it a native form.
2. The suffix "-ien" is a loan from Latin "-ia", which later changed
   its form from Middle High German. So country names that came into
   German via Latin were likely to use this suffix.
3. The suffix "-ei" comes from French "-ie", which also comes from
   Latin "-ia".

As "-ien" is a originally Latin and "-ei" is a originally French suffix, we would expect the names with "-ien" to be older than the ones with "-ei".

But it really seems arbitrary. Just taking Italian regions:
We have "Ligurien", "Emilien" (nowadays "Emilia"), "Sizilien", but "Lombardei", "Romanei" (nowadays "Romagna").

Answer (score 2):

It's arbitrary. For example *Tschechien* had been commonly called *Tschechei* before the late 1990ies, and some of my relatives are from *Kaschubien*. We never said *Kaschubei*.

Comment: "Tschechei" was extremely frowned upon in Czechia because it was used by the Nazis. See https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Tschechei